# Working example of a list targetConfig property in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components

This [Configuration File Tags](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_configuration_tags) documentation talks about **list** support for the `type` value:

> The attribute’s data type. To specify a list, add array notation [] to the end of any data type. These values are valid for all targets:
>
> Boolean
>   Integer
>   String

but for e.g. this:

```
<targetConfigs>
    <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
        <property
            name="PerSlot"
            label="Per slot array"
            type="String[]"
            default="abc, def, ghi"
            required="true"
        />
    </targetConfig>
</targetConfigs>
```

I get this error reported (whatever `apiVersion` I use):

> The attribute type 'String[]' is not supported by one or more of these
>   targets 'lightning__RecordPage'

and removing the `[]` fixes the problem.

Can this list format be made to work?

**PS**

Here is a screenshot of the documentation:

[image: documentation screenshot]

Comment: Seems like the documentation has hidden clause: `These values are valid only if the target is lightning__FlowScreen.`

Comment: @Raul I think that piece in documentation speaks about the Apex Class/Date/DateTime/ObjectName. But looking at the docs it seems Boolean, String, Integer and array type are all valid types for any target.

Comment: @JayantDas the documentation doesn't seem to be correctly written, Same code works for `lightning__FlowScreen`: `targetConfig targets="lightning__FlowScreen"`

Comment: @Keith, could you please specify on what you want to achive. If you want to have a picklist as a option? for that instead of `default` you could try `datasource`.

Comment: @Raul It does seem that docs are missing some piece of information

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation itself mentions that:

> These values are valid only if the target is `lightning__FlowScreen`.

Comment: I think that piece in documentation speaks about the Apex Class/Date/DateTime/ObjectName. But looking at the docs it seems Boolean, String, Integer and array type are all valid types for any target.

Comment: I feel like maybe the line that mentions lists should be below the types list and right before the "these values are valid only..." sentence. I don't think it makes sense to allow a list of parameters in a component configuration outside Flow. On record pages you can't specify lists anyway, but on Flows you can reference flow list variables.

Comment: Honestly I am not sure because haven't tried for myself. But it does seem that there is some missing statement in the docs.

Comment: I took that sentence to relate to the following text where more complex types are discussed.

Comment: This sentence ends in a `.`, not a `:`, so I assume it is referencing the information above it (the basic boolean, integer and string types). But, since list of data doesn't really make sense outside flow, I assume that lists are valid only if you are using the Flow Screen target. This text could be improved.

Answer (score 0):

you should use **datasource** attribute for property:

```
<property label="Status" name="status" type="String" datasource="Active, Locked" default="Active"/>
```

Comment: I believe the question is asking about assigning a *list* to the property and not just a single *string*.

Comment: Seems that List type is not available anymore, so there’s no option to setup multi-select type