# List or String[] is not allowing as parameter from Flow to LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, community, visual-workflow

In salesforce api version 58.0, List (String[]) property is not allowed as parameter in LWC components. Below is the code I'm trying to use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>58.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>

    <targets>
        <target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
    </targets>
    
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__FlowScreen">
            <property name="currentStage" type="String" /> 
            <property name="stages" type="String" label="stages"/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
    
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

VS code is throwing the error as below :

```
'String[]' is not a valid value of union type 'propertyTypeAttr'.
```

Below are the reference links i'm using:

```
https://salesforcegirl.in/2021/05/01/how-to-display-progress-stages-in-flow-by-adding-progress-indicator-component-to-a-flow-screen/

https://www.infallibletechie.com/2021/10/how-to-pass-list-of-string-from-flow-to.html
```

Any help in finding the fix or alternate solution is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked this? - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/289469/working-example-of-a-list-targetconfig-property-in-lwc
- https://www.salesforcelwc.in/use-lwc-in-flows.html

Comment: Yes. My LWC is exposed for 'lightning__FlowScreen'. Refer the code.

Comment: You show the parameter type as just String rather than String[]...?